# Are AVR multi-cycle instructions pipelined?

Tags: avr, assembly, latency

Since AVR is a RISC architecture, most instructions only take a single cycle to execute. Still some need two or more cycles, e.g. `adiw`, which performs 16-bit addition, or `ld` to load data from SRAM.

Do these execution times denote only the latency of these instructions, or does the processor actually wait this long before moving to the next instruction?

Could I run, say, 6 two-cycle instructions, and the entire code would still only need 7 cycles to run?

Comment: Hard to know sometimes, I don’t know about this particular situation. My general suggestion: Compile the code, but edit it in the intermediate assembly stage and force the processor to repeat your instructions a billion times. Then use a good ole’ stopwatch :) With the knowledge of the clock frequency, you can determine if that particular instruction flushed an eventual pipeline or not.

Comment: This is not remotely a practical method.

Comment: @vindarmagnus Instead of stopwatch, use a timer, that's a little more practical! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is nope. An instruction taking 2 cycles to complete will block any further instructions until it is done.

Obligatory quote from ATMega328P datasheet:

> Instructions in the program memory are executed with a single level
>   pipelining. While one instruction is being executed, the next instruction is pre-fetched from the program memory

The pipeline is only single level, so the instruction being fetched cannot start execution until the one currently being executed is finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of the fetch/execute pipeline, but not sure if it rules out any further pipe-lining on other specific parts of the core. Also, according to [this](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_ADIW.html), `adiw`requires 2 cycles. What's your source on this?

Comment: @polwel P33/34 of this: http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf is the reference I use for number of cycles. I think that must be a mistake in that though thinking about it.